# Is it even possible to webscrape this website [Unpredictive URL]?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

This is the website in question (I want to extract the SMR Rating):

https://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nasdaq-apple-inc-aapl.htm

If I have a list of stock names like AAPL, NVDA, TSM etc. and I want to iterate through them, how can I do it when the URL constantly changes in an unpredictable manner?

Take for example the same website with the ticker NVDA:

https://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nasdaq-nvidia-corp-nvda.htm

It's not possible to append the ticker name to the URL and be done with it. I searched for a hidden API and I got this:

https://research.investors.com/services/ChartService.svc/GetData

This website gives me access to a json file but it doesn't contain the desired SMR Rating. Apart from that, I couldn't find anything else that would lead to the SMR Rating. Is this simply impossible?

Here's what I got so far, I can't get even past the HTML reading stage:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests

header = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" ,
'referer':'https://www.google.com/'}

URL = "https://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nasdaq-nvidia-corp-nvda.htm"
page = requests.get(URL, headers = header)

soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

As you can see, I can't load the full html code with beautiful soup, as the page assumes that some form of robotic activity is taking place (Error 405). Should I have specified a different header or is it indeed the case that webscraping isn't allowed on this webapge?

Comment: I mean, you could ask them directly.

Comment: @Barry Carter Do you think they'll help me when they know I'm not a paid subscriber?

Comment: Probably not, but then you're in the grey area of trying to scrape data from someone doesn't want you to have it.

Comment: I'm not sure on your exact requirements for getting this info, but there is always the option of using something like https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html . Which uses tests written in a natural language style, backed up by Python code. This might give you an easier way to navigate info on the page.

Comment: @Barry Carter But then again you can access the SMR Rating individually, by typing out each stock name, for free? Free, albeit inconvenient, does not imply stealing. I could take out a notebook and write everything down manually to be in the white zone, but then I would an r word.

Comment: You should post a minimal reproducible example, and show us your efforts up to this points. It's certainly doable.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire I added my current code now. It seems that the website notices that there's an automated process in the background once I try to access the HTML code...

Comment: @QuantumRain: are you willing to use selenium for this (simplest solution here, from what I can see), and do you have a list of tickers?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire I've never used selenium, though I'm willing to learn. My list of tickers refreshed once a week. These ticker symbols are then put in a list and ready to be used for an iteration process. I usually run a test cycle with AAPL, NVDA, MU, TSM, WTM

Comment: I couldn't find a way to scrape it at scale (for that particular indicator, I mean). It seems page is detecting automation, no matter what. There might be ways to do it, but I don't have the time. Maybe you can derive that indicator from the json response you get for each company from https://research.investors.com/services/ChartService.svc/GetData ?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire I wrote a bit of a selenium code and used this xpath in the find_elements command: //*[@id="stkQteOver-1"]/div/div[2]/ul[6]/li[2]  It didn't help at all as the website automatically recognized that it's an automated attempt at webscraping. The getdata json response doesn't have the sma rating, only the rsRating, epsRating and price history, so it's of no use. I really thought that selenium could outsmart the website, but apparently they're well protected against any scraper. It's not even a timing issue (I only made 1 request), it's just that they know how selenium/bs4 works.

Comment: @QuantumRain by 'deriving' I meant trying to calculate it from the other data points existent in the json response. Is that indicator of so much importance, compared to actual hard data about the company?

Comment: Actually, tell us more about https://research.investors.com/services/ChartService.svc/GetData -- I used web console's network tab (ctrl-shift-k on some browsers) to confirm you do a POST request when you do a search and that POST request eventually redirects to page with info about the company. It appears when you POST to `/services/AutoSuggest.asmx/GetQuoteResults` with payload `{'q':'ccb','limit':10}` you eventually get redirected to CCB's page